# How the ArrayList add() behaves

Tags: java, arrays, performance, arraylist

Consider the following two code snippets:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(0);
for (int i=1; i<10; i++)
    list.add(i);
```

and

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i=1; i<10; i++)
    list.add(i);
list.add(0,0);
```

I would really like to know if there is any performance difference in these two cases? What I was thinking is ArrayList is actually an Object[]...so the 2nd code snippet will need to copy the original array to somewhere, and then create a new one with '0' at position 0...so I think the first approach is indeed better?

Comment: It really is very nearly pointless to worry about performance differences at this level.  If you have a completed project -AND- profiling demonstrates that you have a performance issue in a module ... -then- it is reasonable to consider microoptimizations.  The difference in the code snippets above is likely to be vanishingly small.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ...so the 2nd code snippet will need to copy the original array to somewhere, and then create a new one with '0' at position 0...

It won't have to allocate one if it has enough room in its current one (which, with that code, it will using Oracle's implementation — *just*, it defaults to an initial capacity of 10). But it does have to shuffle things around.

> ...so I think the first approach is indeed better?

Definitely, and for the reason you gave. The second block just needlessly makes the `ArrayList` move things around in the underlying array.

(Not that it's likely to matter much, unless this is in a really tight loop being run millions of times... But still.)

Answer (score 2):

The first option is better.  In general sequential access is faster, but the first example is also clearer IMHO.

You can check the source if you really want to know, however

```
list.add(0, 0);
```

shuffles the elements down the underlying array. It only creates a new array if it doesn't have enough capacity in the same way the `list.add(i)` has to do.

Answer (score 0):

The second approach will shift the other elements in the Arraylist and thus introduced a performance issue. See [this doc link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29). It will create new array only if there is no room.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is just better practice, but in this case neither has a distinct advantage. Despite what the other answers say, ArrayLists do not take time inserting one element no matter where it is. That is to say, inserting `0` at the beginning is constant. Note that if you are inserting more than one element, however, time is O(n) where n is the number of items you are inserting.

When I ran a few tests on both of those code snippets, here are the results:

```
794913915
703911773
```

and

```
838856889
942264566
```

so you can see that when you are inserting one element, it does not really matter. Note: this test inserted `100` items instead of `10`, but the results for `10` were the same. However, if we run the same test except the first case inserts `100` items first and the second case inserts `100` items at the beginning of the list later, here are the results:

```
1316759001
8390794221
```

The "better practice" approach takes much less time.